# App crashes on increase of Target SDK Version

Tags: android, sdk, target

I'm programming an Android app and tried to increase the `android:targetSdkVersion` to 19 to get rid of the warning `"Not targeting the latest versions of Android..."`. Before i used version 10 and everything worked pretty well but after that i got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1438)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1388)
at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:824)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:4450)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1190)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4860)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:766)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:575)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried all versions between 10 and 19 and figured out that this error occurs if i choose version 14 or higher.
Because none of the messages comes from my code directly I'm not sure where to look for the error.
Can anyone tell me what i should look for? Does anyone know what changed from v13 to v14 that could explain this behaviour?

Comment: My project contains nearly 230 java files plus some external librarys and i have no idea where this error comes from. I would have add all of them. Thats the reason for the question. I really don't now where to start searching.

Comment: but it crashes in certain moment so you can run debugger, plant breakpoint and then do in step-by-step to see where it crashes

Comment: Thats right. But right in this moment pretty much happens. I'm starting new Activitys, calling methods from background activitys, do bigger calculations and draw on canvas. I will try to find where the error occurs.

Comment: I solved the problem. I called getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD) in one activity. without this it works. But I have to use API v13 after all because canvas.clipPath() is no longer supported in v14 :(